# Using nvarchar(MAX) to build query, but conversion fails in where clause

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that uses a variable called `@Command (nvarchar(MAX))`. I then add parameters accordingly based on given input.

```
declare @Command nvarchar(max)
if(@CaseFileID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
select @Command='
  select [ServerCredentialsID],[CaseFileID],EIKSLT.[LocationType],EPT.PaymentType,[TaskID],[DateActive]
      ,[LengthOfPurchase],[Username],[Password],[IPDomain],[Port],[DES],[Website],[AmountPaid],[Latitude]
      ,[Longitude],[HasAttachments],[TimeStamp],[CaseElement],[Temporary],[StatusID] 
      FROM Element17a_IKSServerCredentials EIKSSC 
      JOIN ElementsIKSLocationTypes EIKSLT ON EIKSSC.LocationBeingUsedID= EIKSLT.IKSLocationBeingUsedID 
      JOIN ElementsPaymentTypes EPT ON EIKSSC.PaymentMethodID=EPT.PaymentTypeID 
      where  EIKSSC.CaseFileID='''+cast(@CaseFileID as nvarchar(MAX))+''' '
```

@CaseFileID is declared as an int, and in the table it is an int. When I try

```
where  EIKSSC.CaseFileID = ' + @CaseFileID + ' '
```

then the value doesn't even show (in the error it looks like `"EIKSSC.CaseFileID=  '"` )

I just don't get it.

NOTE: SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Comment: what is the value of @CaseFileID?

Comment: I just enter 9. because the CaseFileID I'm trying to get is 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because @CaseFileID is VARCHAR even though you don't show it.
Your `IF` should be

```
if(@CaseFileID > '')
```

And if even that doesn't work, then you need to swap to LEFT joins because INNER JOINs will remove records that cannot be matched in the other 2 tables.

Finally, because CaseFileID is an int, you don't need the quotes.  Even though SQL Server will implicitly cast '9' to the integer 9 in the `WHERE` clause, it's just not necessary.

```
declare @Command nvarchar(max)
if(@CaseFileID > '')
BEGIN
select @Command='
  select [ServerCredentialsID],[CaseFileID],EIKSLT.[LocationType],EPT.PaymentType,[TaskID],[DateActive]
      ,[LengthOfPurchase],[Username],[Password],[IPDomain],[Port],[DES],[Website],[AmountPaid],[Latitude]
      ,[Longitude],[HasAttachments],[TimeStamp],[CaseElement],[Temporary],[StatusID] 
      FROM Element17a_IKSServerCredentials EIKSSC 
      LEFT JOIN ElementsIKSLocationTypes EIKSLT ON EIKSSC.LocationBeingUsedID= EIKSLT.IKSLocationBeingUsedID 
      LEFT JOIN ElementsPaymentTypes EPT ON EIKSSC.PaymentMethodID=EPT.PaymentTypeID 
      where  EIKSSC.CaseFileID='+cast(@CaseFileID as nvarchar(MAX))
```

Comment: Thank you for the Help. I definitely implemented your work. However the problem was actually the fact that I never converted my other parameters. If you can put that in your answer so others can see then I'll also appreciate it. I would answer my own question but your suggestion seems a lot more in depth.